# sequelize TypeError: "value" argument is out of bounds

Tags: sequelize.js

This may be related to these issues on github:

https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/47
https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/202

I just began experiencing this situation after upgrading sequelize from v4 to v5. I had to also upgrade tedious to v6.4.

It seems it is a tedious issue, that occurs when using sequelize for ms sql server. The whole issue crashes the application because, it appears, tedious does not handle the error correctly.

In my case, it occurs when I try to make an update or insert in a table that has a *money* field. This amount: -1328238.3, for example, makes this issue to occur in my case. The model to define the table in sequelize uses the *Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2)* type.

So, the issue appears in a totally random way. Much of the time, updates and inserts occur just fine. Occasionally, you have an update with certain amount, like the one I showed before, that makes the issue to occur.

This is an specific example of an update that fails, when the amount is -1328238.3:

```
SaldosContables_sql.update(
    {
        inicial: saldoAnoFiscalActual.anual,
    },
    { where: {
        cuentaContableID: saldoAnoFiscalActual.cuentaContableID,
        ano: anoFiscalProximo,
        moneda: saldoAnoFiscalActual.moneda,
        monedaOriginal: saldoAnoFiscalActual.monedaOriginal,
    }}
)
```

What I had to do, at least for some time, to make my application run, was to make the whole update with a simple query, and pass the amount as a string using x.toFixed(2).

I'm using these versions of sequelize and tedious:

"sequelize": "5.19.0",
"tedious": "6.4.0",

Some help would be very appreciated, 
Thanks and bye ...

Comment: As I said before, I'm assuming this is a tedious issue. In sequelize v5 docs, it states:

_Sequelize now works with tedious >= 6.0.0_

I never had this issue before. So, I think previous versions of tedious didn't have this issue. I'm wondering if I can use another tedious version, previous to v6. At least to test everything and see if the issue disappears.

Comment: Well, didn't receive answers to this question. To solve this issue, which I thing is sooo grave, at least for me, I just did a downgrade from versions: sequelize: 5.19.0, tedious: 6.4.0, to versions: sequelize: 4.41.2, tedious: 1.14.0. Of course the error disappeared and everything is running smoothly now. I think I'll wait for sequelize version 6 to test everything out again.